# what's wrong with appium launch that my program ended with timeout when trying to connect to appium server?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, selenium, appium

I'm new to appium.
I'm working on windows 7, and followed the instructions [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?csharp#running-appium-on-windows)

I wrote a tiny program in C#(visual studio) that connects to appium server. however, the program ends with the failure message: 'the http request to the remote webdriver server for URLhttp://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session timed out.
I don't get why it happens. I think I provide everything required.
in any case, here's the log displayed on appium server:

> 2016-01-20 13:00:40:391 - info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   2016-01-20 13:00:40:394 - info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","logTimestamp":true,"logNoColors":true,"androidPackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","androidActivity":"com.android.deskclock.DeskClock","avd":"TestDevice","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   2016-01-20 13:00:40:395 - info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:497 - info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"TestDevice","apppackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","platformName":"Android"}}
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:499 - info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:500 - info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : apppackage
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:502 - info: [debug] Using local app from command line: C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:503 - info: [debug] Creating new appium session c67e396c-58c6-4c45-a4be-7561171b6a2b
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:504 - info: Starting android appium
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:505 - info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:582 - info: Java version is: 1.7.0_45
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:583 - info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:584 - info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:584 - info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:585 - info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:585 - info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:585 - info: [debug] Trying to find TestDevice emulator
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:585 - info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:586 - info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:587 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:613 - info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:614 - info: [debug] 2 emulator(s) connected
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:614 - info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:614 - info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:615 - info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:616 - info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:618 - info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:618 - info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:620 - info: [debug] Telnet command got response: TestDevice
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:621 - info: [debug] Found emulator TestDevice in port 5554
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:621 - info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:621 - info: [debug] Did not launch AVD because it was already running.
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:622 - info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:623 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:652 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:01:813 - info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:074 - info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:075 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:467 - info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:468 - info: Device API level is: 23
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:468 - info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:469 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:615 - error: Unhandled error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1012:19) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"TestDevice","apppackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","platformName":"Android"}}]
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:982 - info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
>   2016-01-20 13:01:02:983 - info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\com.google.android.deskclock" 
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:796 - info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:797 - info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:797 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\com.google.android.deskclock\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:855 - info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:856 - info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:856 - info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:857 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:896 - info: [debug] Set app process to: com.google.android.deskclock
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:896 - info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:897 - info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk.
>   2016-01-20 13:01:04:897 - info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:164 - info: [debug] App already signed.
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:164 - info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:164 - info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:165 - info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:166 - info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:167 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\116020-9204-xzuy8n\appium.tmp
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:230 - info: [debug] MD5 for app is 1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:230 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:631 - info: [debug] Getting install status for com.google.android.deskclock
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:631 - info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:631 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:962 - info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   2016-01-20 13:01:05:963 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.google.android.deskclock"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:12:464 - info: [debug] App is not installed
>   2016-01-20 13:01:12:464 - info: Installing App
>   2016-01-20 13:01:12:465 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:12:777 - info: [debug] Removing any old apks
>   2016-01-20 13:01:12:777 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:13:088 - info: [debug] Found an apk we want to keep at /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
>   2016-01-20 13:01:13:089 - info: [debug] Couldn't find any apks to remove
>   2016-01-20 13:01:13:089 - info: [debug] Uninstalling com.google.android.deskclock
>   2016-01-20 13:01:13:089 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.google.android.deskclock"
>   2016-01-20 13:01:18:439 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.google.android.deskclock
>   2016-01-20 13:01:24:088 - info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?
>   2016-01-20 13:01:24:088 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
>   2016-01-20 13:04:31:462 - info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - - 
>   undefined

In my settings I selected:
application path
package
launch avd.

Is there anything else I had to select?

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at exports._errnoException`. Could be that. I'm struggling to find the motivation to parse that wall of text, to be honest. Can you provide details of how far you got with debugging to try and narrow it down?

Comment: It is probably that connection refused error, but I also saw this `The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : apppackage`. Change that to "appPackage". Also, what devices appear when you input `adb devices` in command line?

Comment: changed to appPackage but the problem was not resolved yet. The devices are:emulator-5612 host, and emulator-5554 device. 'JayMee'- I saw that error but I don't get what's wrong..maybe something not work fine with Apache..how can I check it out? the text above was everything appeared by the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the port no in appium sever(from 4723 to 4729 etc) and in your code and use it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port as you said, and now the output is:

```
     Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4729 --app     C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk --app-pkg com.google.android.deskclock --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4729
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\deskclock.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","port":4729,"logNoColors":true,"androidPackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"TestDevice","appPackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","platformName":"Android"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
> info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] Using local app from command line: C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session f5d04763-da99-4878-a8af-b58706cfa7d3
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.7.0_45
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe dump badging C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] badging package: com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] badging act: com.android.deskclock.DeskClock
> info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.DeskClock
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: Device API level is: 23
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
> info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
> info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\com.google.android.deskclock" 
> info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
> info: [debug] Setting language to default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.google.android.deskclock\\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk AndroidManifest.xml
> info: [debug] Set app process to: com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
> info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] App already signed.
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
> info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\116021-13616-hyr32n\appium.tmp
> info: [debug] MD5 for app is 1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> info: [debug] Getting install status for com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.google.android.deskclock"
> info: [debug] App is not installed
> info: Installing App
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/"
> info: [debug] Removing any old apks
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"
> info: [debug] Found an apk we want to keep at /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
> info: [debug] Couldn't find any apks to remove
> info: [debug] Uninstalling com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.google.android.deskclock"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - - 
> undefined
```

however, the program ends with failure messageL http request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4729/wd/hub timed out after 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

@adib1 Now the issue is

> Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   You should be using User-Agent field which isnt defined. Remove it if its not necessary to run the program

To find the user agent you can use the JAvaScript executor as below

```
// Get the UserAgent from device
                JavascriptExecutor je=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                System.out.println(je.executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;",new Object[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed some things (such as adding HAXM..)and now the output is:

```
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4729 --app C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk --full-reset --intent-category android.intent.category.LAUNCHER --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --device-name "TestDevice" --log-no-color
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4729
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\deskclock.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","port":4729,"fullReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"deviceName":"TestDevice","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"deviceName":"TestDevice","appPackage":"com.google.android.deskclock","platformName":"Android"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
> info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
> info: [debug] Using local app from command line: C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 627ce8be-ee54-4b54-8cf3-77ec92082c2e
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.7.0_45
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe" dump badging C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] badging package: com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] badging act: com.android.deskclock.DeskClock
> info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.DeskClock
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
 > info: Found device emulator-5554
 > info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
 > info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: Device API level is: 23
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
> info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
> info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\com.google.android.deskclock" 
> info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
> info: [debug] Setting language to default
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.google.android.deskclock\\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
> info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
> info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
> info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe" dump xmltree C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk AndroidManifest.xml
> info: [debug] Set app process to: com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] Uninstalling com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.google.android.deskclock"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?
> info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] App already signed.
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk
> info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
> info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
> info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe" -f 4 C:\Users\User\Desktop\deskclock.apk C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\116024-8840-1wyj0b7\appium.tmp
> info: [debug] MD5 for app is 1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> info: [debug] Getting install status for com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.google.android.deskclock"
> info: [debug] App is not installed
> info: Installing App
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/"
> info: [debug] Removing any old apks
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android- sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"
> info: [debug] Found an apk we want to keep at /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
> info: [debug] Couldn't find any apks to remove
> info: [debug] Uninstalling com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.google.android.deskclock"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.google.android.deskclock
> info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> warn: Installing remote apk failed, going to uninstall and try again
> info: [debug] Removing any old apks
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell rm "/data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\deskclock.apk" /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
> info: [debug] Attempting to install again for the last time
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
> 
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
> info: [debug] Error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk
> 
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
>     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1358:17
>     at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER])","origValue":"Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/1ecaef182f19717b64e1f5caac138b85.apk\r\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 29229.525 ms - 384
```

why is INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER happening?